# Remove and Commit Fragment yet it's still in getSupportFragment Manager

Tags: android, fragment, commit

Any thoughts on why the fragment is not getting removed?  This is an interface method being called from a 'AsyncTask' fragment with retaininstance(true).  In the test of remove mTaskFragment is not equal to null so the log line prints.

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(boolean success, String result, String message) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");


    //Remove the Fragment if its still there
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mTaskFragment = (MyAsyncTaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);
    if (mTaskFragment != null) {
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(mTaskFragment).commit();
    }
    mTaskFragment = null;


    //Test of remove
    mTaskFragment = (MyAsyncTaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_FRAGMENT);
    if (mTaskFragment != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mTaskFragment is not null");
    }
```

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s happen asynchronously. If you want the `remove()` to happen ASAP, call `executePendingTransactions()` on the `FragmentManager` right after the `commit()`.

Comment: Thanks that was all that I needed.